# how to pass an object value to 2 jsp pages via spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have 2 model class

```
public class Abcd {

    private String name;
    private String familyName;

// getters and setters
}

public class Bcd {

    private String color;

// getters and setters
}
```

i want that 1st jsp page takes input for Abcd, and then pass it to 2nd jsp page, where i also take input for the BCD class and then i show both objects input data to the 3rd page

please suggest the way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `Abcd`'s `name` and `family` in hidden fields on the second page. The action calling the third page would be able to access to `Abcd`'s and `Bcd`'s attributes and show them in the third JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this object into one object:

```
public class Wizard {
   private Abcd first;
   private Bcd  second;

    // setters, gettes
}
```

Then in your controller put:
@SessionAttribute("wizard")
public class WizardController {

```
@ModelAttribute("wizard")
public Wizard modelWizar() {
  return new Wizard();
}
```

}

For more information go to Spring reference http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib

If you are using Spring version < 2.5 then you can use

AbstractWizardFormController which is deprecated in newest version of spring.